# prevent apt* from downloading behind my back

Tags: debian, apt, deb

I am on Debian Sid and I've found that an `apt-upgrade` didn't
download all the 87 packages that were to be installed but just one,
that was not in the debian's repositories (namely
`http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 google-chrome-stable`)
and proceeded with the install.

This behavior led me to assume that some subsystem had previously
downloaded the necessary `.deb`s.  While in general there is no harm
in that, I'd prefer to choose when the download happens because I
sometimes have a pretty fast connection and sometimes a very poor one,
where I'd like to have every kbyte/s at my disposal...

My question is twofold

1. is it possible that `apt`, or one of its siblings, is really downloading
   the `.deb`s behind my back, and which is the machinery involved?
2. can I have this not happen (if it is really happening)?

Tia

Answer (score 3):

It's possibly due to the `unattended-upgrades` configuration in your Debian system. `unattended-upgrades` has been introduced to keep your system up-to-date with respect to security and other updates.

You can configure `unattended-upgrades` to enabled/disabled by modifying its configuration file: `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades`

For more information read: https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades

Comment: My PC stopped downloading `.deb` s in advance just a few days following me asking this Q, so I left any focus on my Q... I cannot accept your answer (because I don't know if it _would have_ worked for me) but I like to recognize its merits. ፨ ps: i have no `NNauto-upgrades` configuration file...